# What sort of answer does Spivak expect to Problem 2-13(d) from Calculus on Manifolds?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Problem 2-13 from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* asks the following:

> **Problem 2-13.** Define $IP : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $IP(x,y) = \langle x, y \rangle$.
>
> 1. Find $D(IP)(a,b)$ and $(IP)'(a,b)$.
> 2. If $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable and $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $h(t) = \langle f(t), g(t) \rangle$, show that $$h'(a) = \langle f'(a)^T, g(a) \rangle + \langle f(a), g'(a)^T \rangle.$$
> 3. If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|f(t)| = 1$ for all $t$, show that $\langle f'(t)^T, f(t) \rangle = 0$.
> 4. Exhibit a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the function $|f|$ defined by $|f|(t) = |f(t)|$ is not differentiable.

What I find weird is that part (4) of the problem seems quite unrelated to the previous three parts of the question. The first three parts are specifically about the inner product as a multilinear function and the properties it and its derivative have, whereas for part (4) I can just take $f(x) = x$ and be done with it.

Typically, Spivak's problems are set up in a way to motivate some deeper idea. It is possible that he has slipped up here (after all, *Calculus on Manifolds* has numerous typos as well). But, I'd still like to ask,

> Is there a way to look at part (4) of this problem in such a way that it connects to the inner product (or more precisely, to the previous three parts of the problem)?

Comment: Maybe Spivak's point is that, although differentiable $f$ and $g$ give you a differentiable inner product function $h$ as in part (2), the square root, $\sqrt h$, which is relevant to computing distances and angles, need not be differentiable. So you shouldn't use the "good news" in the first three parts to jump to a "bad" conclusion that lengths and angles will also be good.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That is a very reasonable interpretation. Would you mind if I add your comment to my answer below (with appropriate credit, of course)? I can make it community wiki too, if you would prefer that. If you would like to turn it into a full-fledged answer on its own, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Okay, here's the best that I am able to do, even though it is just a disguised way of saying that $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ is not differentiable at $0$.*

---

Choose the functions $f$ and $g$ from part (2) as $f(x) = (x,x,\dotsc,x)$ and $g(x) = (1,1,\dotsc,1)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, and so is $h(t) = \langle f(t),g(t) \rangle = nt$. But, $\lvert h \rvert (t) = n \lvert t \rvert$, which is not differentiable at $0$. Hence, $\lvert h \rvert$ is not differentiable even though $h$ is differentiable.